# Bjoern is 4x faster than Nginx - how to tweak Nginx to handle Bjoern proxy_requests without performance loss?

Tags: nginx, python, redis

I was trying to put [Bjoern](https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern) behind Nginx for easy load-balancing and DoS/DDoS attack mitigation.

To my dismay I not only discovered that it drops connections like chips (it varies between 20% and 50% of total connections), but it seems actually faster when not put behind it.

This was tested on a machine with 6GB RAM and Dual-Core 2Ghz cpu.

My app is this:

```
import bjoern,redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

val = r.get('test:7')

def hello_world(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    res = val
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type','text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length',str(len(res)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [res]

# despite the name this is not a hello world as you can see
bjoern.run(hello_world, 'unix:/tmp/bjoern.sock')
```

Nginx configuration:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 52000; # worker_connections * 2
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 18000;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    charset                         utf-8;
    client_body_timeout             65;
    client_header_timeout           65;
    client_max_body_size            10m;
    default_type                    application/octet-stream;
    keepalive_timeout               20;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    send_timeout                    65;
    server_tokens                   off;
    sendfile                        on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;
    tcp_nodelay                     off;
    tcp_nopush                      on;


    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and virtual host:

```
upstream backend {
server unix:/tmp/bjoern.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    location / {
        proxy_buffering     off;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_pass         http://backend;
    }
}
```

The benchmark of Bjoern put behind Nginx through unix socket I get is this:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        nginx
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        148 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   0.983 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        3
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 3, Exceptions: 0)
Non-2xx responses:      3
Total transferred:      3000078 bytes
HTML transferred:       1480054 bytes
Requests per second:    10170.24 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       98.326 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.098 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2979.64 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   15   4.8     15      35
Processing:    11   28  19.2     19     223
Waiting:        7   24  20.4     16     218
Total:         16   43  20.0     35     225

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     35
  66%     38
  75%     40
  80%     40
  90%     79
  95%     97
  98%    109
  99%    115
 100%    225 (longest request)
```

10k requests per second, lesser failed requests this time but still..

When Bjoern is hit directly benchmarks results are the following:

*After changing `bjoern.run(hello_world, 'unix:/tmp/bjoern.sock')` to `bjoern.run(hello_world, "127.0.0.1", 8000)`*

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        148 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.193 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    10000
Total transferred:      2380000 bytes
HTML transferred:       1480000 bytes
Requests per second:    51904.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.927 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.019 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          12063.77 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       4
Processing:     1    2   0.4      2       5
Waiting:        0    2   0.4      2       5
Total:          1    2   0.5      2       5

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      2
  66%      2
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%      2
  95%      3
  98%      4
  99%      4
 100%      5 (longest request)
```

50k requests per second and not even a failed request in this case.

I have extensively tweaked system variables such as **somaxconn** etc, if not I think I wouldn't get that many requests with Bjoern alone anyway.

How is it possible that Bjoern is so massively faster than Nginx?

I'm really concerned about not being able to use Nginx and benefit from the things outlined in the first line and hope you can help me find where the culprit is.

The short and concise question is: How to proxy_pass Bjoern to Nginx without losing in terms of performance? Should I just stay with Bjoern and achieve load-balancing and DoS/DDoS attack mitigation another way?

Comment: These tests are not comparable; they are testing two completely different things. One is simply serving a static piece of text. The other is actually doing _work_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you pinpoint precisely where? They are both executing the same script. Shouldn't Bjoern be slower then as it's the one "doing the work" while Nginx "proxying" it?

Comment: Bjoern isn't doing anything more than serving "hello world". If you have nginx do the same thing, then it will be faster too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton And what is Nginx doing then, sitting idle?

Comment: You are having nginx proxy all its connections! You already knew this, why did you ask?

Comment: @MichaelHampton My thought was that something like this was happening: `client -> nginx -> bjoern -> nginx -> client`. So the conclusion is not to put Bjoern behind Nginx as it will degrade performance and just decide between Bjoern and Nginx?

Comment: Effort is wasted when you are going in the wrong direction!

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for the tip! I'm already in the right path after the answer which clarified the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the answer is given in the article below.

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2036661

> For example, let's consider this thought experiment: Someone here
> mentioned Mongrel2 getting 4000 req/sec. Let's replace the name
> "Mongrel2" with "Server A" because this thought experiment is not
> limited to Mongrel2, but all servers. I assume he's benchmarking a
> hello world app on his laptop. Suppose that a hypothetical Server B
> gets "only" 2000 req/sec. One might now (mistakenly) conclude that:
>
> - Server B is a lot slower.
> - One should use Server A instead of Server B in high-traffic production environments.
>
> Now put Server A behind HAProxy. HAproxy is
> known as a high-performance HTTP proxy server with minimal overhead.
> Benchmark this setup, and watch req/sec drop to about 2000-3000 (when
> benchmarked on a typical dual core laptop).
>
> What just happened? Server
> B appears to be very slow. But the reality is that both Server A and
> Server B are so fast that doing even a minimum amount of extra work
> will have a significant effect on the req/sec number. In this case,
> the overhead of an extra context switch and a read()/write() call to
> the kernel is already enough to make the req/sec number drop by half.
> Any reasonably complex web app logic will make the number drop so much
> that the performance difference between the different servers become
> negligible.